# Firebase databaseAuthVariableOverride not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I followed these [Firebase directions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) and over the past few weeks I've been using the `databaseAuthVariableOverride` to let users use Algolia to run search results in my app and access the database. I changed my Firebase Service Account API key earlier today and now the `databaseAuthVariableOverride` no longer works and I cannot access the database.

Before I changed my Api Key everything was working fine when I set my rules and app.js file to :

Firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid === 'my-service-worker'", // matches the databaseAuthVariableOverride
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

and my App.js file to:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: .....,
    privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----oldPrivateKey----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    clientEmail: .....
  }),
  databaseURL: .....,
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
       uid: "my-service-worker" // matches the rules
    }
});
```

When I changed my Service Account I went *ProjectOverview* > *ProjectSettings* > *ServiceAccounts* > *Generate New Private Key*. After pressing *Generate New Private Key* a new key was downloaded to my cpu. 
[image]

I checked the permissions inside `IAM` and the Service Account Client Email is set to `Editor`.

I then took the new private key that was generated that looks like `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----newPrivateKey----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n`and copied and pasted into my app.js file where my old private key had been set:

```
admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert({
        // my new private key
        privateKey: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----newPrivateKey----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

Now the only way it works is if i set my Firebase rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

The API Key has to work otherwise I wouldn't be able read anything with the rules being set to `true`

When I try to do the things the original way I had when set the rules to match `my-service-worker` the `app.js` file is no longer granted access to the database.

In the comments @Doug Stevenson suggested that I change all the  fields that came with the new Service Account but the problem is I only used 3 fields from the old Service Account of of those 3 the only thing that was changed was the Private Key. The other 2 fields have the same values.
There are several others that I never used to begin with:

[image]

These are the values that are used inside the `app.js` file:

[image]

**What could be the problem?**

**UPDATE**
@Doug Stevenson's said that every time a new Service Account is generated, a new Client Email should get generated with it too. I generated 5 Service Accounts and the first 4 kept the same Client Email. I'm not sure why that happened but I went to the Google Cloud Console, generated my own, deleted the old ones and nothing worked. I then went back to the Firebase console with the blue button, pressed it, and then I got a new Client Email. It took me 5 Service Account downloads to change it??? Anyhow I updated the values with new Client Email and it's associated Private Key and my problems still persist. I also checked the permissions and it's set to Editor.

I emailed Firebase for help and I'm waiting for a response.

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain exactly what you did when you "changed my Firebase Service Account API key"?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initialized the database twice and that was why the databaseAuthVariableOverride wasn't working correctly.

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL
  }),
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: process.env.TOKEN
  }
});

// 1st initialization
const db = admin.database();
const firstRef = db.ref(process.env.INDEX_NAME); // I only needed to use this
firstRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});

// ****2nd initialization****
const secondRef = firebase.database().ref(process.env.INDEX_NAME); // this second initialization was causing a problem with the first one
```

The 2nd initialization caused the databaseAuthVariableOverride not to work. Once I commented it out the databaseAuthVariableOverride started working every time I changed it from a value to null and back.

I only need to use `firstRef` as the base reference and everything was all good.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace service account, you need to update ALL of the certificate field values, not just the privateKey field.

Instead, ideally, you are just replacing the entire JSON file that you `require()` from your project.  This is probably much better than hard coding everything in the source file, especially if your project is open source and you don't want to share your credentials with the world.  Or even with your coworkers who have different project sandboxes that they're using also for development.

Comment: Hey Doug thanks. I actually use .env variables with .gitignore but didn't add it because I didn't want to overcomplicate the question. The other certificate fields that are included in the service account don't coincide with any of the other values

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting.  Are you saying that you tried replacing all the fields and are still stuck?

Comment: I took a screen shot of what was inside the Service Account file, now I'll take a screen shot of what's  inside my app.js file. I have to obscure the keys

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from simply copying all those fields and values from the file into your code?  That's what my answer is suggesting that you need to do - not just the privateKey Field.   The instructions are pretty clear for setup that you should be using the entire service account file to init the admin SDK.

Comment: I adde a picture of the values that are inside the app.js file

Comment: Client email should be different in the new service account.  Copy it over.

Comment: I thought about what you said and double checked everything, it's exactly the same. I even followed this link and deleted the old service account Key ID. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys. The same email key is there too.

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  It should be uniquely identifying that service account.

Comment: I just generated a new new one, the client email is exactly the same. As a matter of fact when you go to ProjectOverview > ProjectSettings > ServiceAccounts > Generate New Private Key the client email address that is above the blue button is the same exact client email that is generated with the new keys. It never changes

Comment: My mistake, I was looking at a really old credential file of mine before some conventions changed.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you - you've deviated from the normal instructions more than I've ever seen anyone do before.

Comment: Lol, I’ve been trying to figure this out for at least 10 hours. I have no idea what the problem is. It’s baffling

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is going to the cloud console and deleting all the old admin sdk service accounts for the project: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Comment: FYI: "A service account is identified by its email address, which is unique to the account." - https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts.  Wonder what's going on here.

Comment: I went to the cloud console, created a new one, deleted the old one, it still didn't work (same client email). I then went back to the Firebase console (where the blue button is) created yet another one and then bang, the email was finally changed. It took 5 service account downloads for the email to change??? I then went and deleted the one I created in the cloud console, switched my Service Account and Client Email fields in my question example and it's still not working. I emailed Firebase last night for help. Once they get back to me and this is fixed I'll mssg you. THANKS!

Comment: So, I discovered that the way the Firebase service account works is that there really is a single account that gets reused, and every time you request new keys from it, they are just added to that same account.  You have to delete the firebase-admin service account entirely (in the Cloud console, and not just the individual keys).  Then when you go back to the Firebase console, it will see there is no service account, and create another one for you, with a new email address.  But I still don't understand why creating new keys in your original account didn't work.

Comment: It's very confusing because I went to the google cloud, created a new one, then deleted the old ones from there and it still didn't work. Not until I went back to the fb console (blue button) and generated a new one did it finally update. I deleted the one that I created in the google cloud console. I posted this q&a and used admin.database.enableLogging(true) and now I can see that the databaseAuthVariableOverride is working: "d":{"auth":{"uid":"my-service-worker"}. I would love to know why it took 5 downloads for the client email to finally change though? Very strange.

Comment: I forgot to update you with the resolution. The problem was I initialized the same ref twice. The second initialization caused the databaseAuthVariableOverride not to work. Please read the answer. Thanks for the help!